# Error: Required named parameter 'vsync' must be provided

Tags: flutter, dart

I run project and I don't edit anything on it then it throw this exception

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/getwidget-2.0.5/lib/components/animation/gf_animation.dart:244:28: Error: Required named parameter 'vsync' must be provided.
        child: AnimatedSize(
                           ^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/animated_size.dart:56:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const AnimatedSize({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

How fix this error to run project please help me and thank you

Comment: Can you find the file named **gf_animation.dart** and make sure it implements the mixin **TickerProviderStateMixin**, and inside of that **const AnimatedSize** make sure it has (if not, add it) the **vsync: this** parameter. That's weird that this project  didn't have - is this like a sample project you got from somewhere?

Comment: @RomanJaquez this project from git and I run it for the first time, so I add 'with TickerProviderStateMixin' to GFAnimation class and add this to 'vsync: this,' to child: AnimatedSize and it still throw errors

Comment: What version the flutter sdk you used? Starting from version v2.2.0-10.1.pre the parameter vsync is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The animation package you're using is breaking the build, I'd suggest you revert to the last working update of the package, most packages get this error after shifting to null safety.

Some things are missed and it ends up breaking app, so move to the last working update, then raise an issue on the repository.